# HTML split table cell instead of using colspan

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with lots of rows and columns.

[image]

Now I want split td "E8" in 2 columns like this:

[image]

What is the best solution?

Comment: Wrap those 2 values inside div and either give `border-bottom` to first div or give `border-top` to second div!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One Way:**

You can user `rowspan="2"` on all other cells in the same row

Example:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is an [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5LzmC/)

**Another Way**

inside the cell you put two `divs` and use `css` to style it

*HTML:*

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <div class="top">Top</div>
            <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*CSS:*

```
.top{
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.bottom{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

and you can see an [EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5LzmC/2/)

Comment: Yes but it is a bit cumbersome because if you have a large table, you need to insert a lot of "rowspan"...

Comment: The other way I am thinking about it to use divs inside that cell, but again, it requires extra work!  You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5LzmC/2/

Comment: Taking in mind Dhaval Marthak tip, I have updated the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/5LzmC/2/

Answer (score 1):

Put two rows within that cell

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id = "E1">
    <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Actually this is inserting a table inside a cell, `nested table`, and it slow the page load